# QueryDSL with inner join containing MAX() and Group By

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I'm wondering if anyone can give me any pointers on  writing the following query using QueryDSL JPA?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      type,
      max(UPDATED) AS updated
    FROM TABLE1
    where status='COMPLETED'
    GROUP BY type
    )
  USING (type, updated);
```

Thanks.

Comment: It can be useful http://www.querydsl.com/

Comment: yup, big fan of QueryDsl, used it a lot, I've read the docs, but this query is not exactly standard jpa. I couldn't find it covered in the docs. Spent considerable time trying with QueryDsl.

Answer (score 0):

In JPA and Querydsl JPA you can use subqueries only in the WHERE part. Only joins are done in JPA via properties, not columns.

It looks like SQL and Querydsl SQL are a better match in this case.